# How to deal with postponed CMD prompt in C#?

Tags: c#, cmd, process

I'm making a very simple app that can lock/unlock drive encrypted by BitLocker.

Locking is pretty simple, just create cmd process and add command as argument:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c manage-bde -lock p: -forcedismount");
```

However unlocking is a bit tricky, since it wants me to prompt a password. Not by an argument, but after I prompt the first command, as you can see in the attached image.
Is there a way I can solve this by injecting that password somehow?

PS: I'm aware there is a NuGet package available for working with BitLocker, but that's not what I'm looking for.

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that you'd have to use the Win API (possibly `SendMessage`) to simulate the keys of the password being pressed to the `cmd` window to '_type_' the password in

Comment: *"I'm aware there is a NuGet package available for working with BitLocker, but that's not what I'm looking for"* why not?

Comment: No experience with `manage-bde`, but `manage-bde -unlock /?` states, `-password` is to ask the user for a password, while `-recoverypassword ...` provides a password (not tested).